# Audit: Who changed the master page?

Tags: 2013, master-page, sharepoint-on-prem, auditing

How can I know who changed the master page for the site, do the audit logs cater such information? If yes, how should I generate report to see this information?

Comment: Version history? Or were it updated using some type of admin account?

Comment: Not the changes within the master page file, but who change the master page for particular site.

Comment: Ah, well you should be able to see who clicked the link to your site + /_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx from the audit log Content Viewing or Content Modification

Comment: That could give a hint, let me check